# AE.Net.Mail unit testing - Verifying email exists in Inbox

Tags: c#, unit-testing, gmail-imap

I have started using AE.Net.Mail in an attempt to log into one of our test 
accounts and verify whether an email (Unseen) exists in the Inbox based on unique Subject and email Body.
I have created a Unit test project in VSE 2013 and trying to get 'pass' of 'fail'
by using an Assertion. I'm able to print out results but the assertion always pass which does not make sense. 
Any ideas ?

```
namespace GmailAccessUnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string imapAddr = "imap.gmail.com";
            int portNo = 993;
            bool secureConn = true;

            string myEmailID = "a@sample.com";
            string myPasswd =  "pass";

            using (ImapClient ic = new ImapClient(imapAddr, myEmailID, myPasswd, ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, portNo, secureConn))
            {
                ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
                bool headersOnly = false;
                Lazy<MailMessage>[] messages = ic.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen(), headersOnly);

                foreach (Lazy<MailMessage> message in messages)
                {
                    MailMessage m = message.Value;

                    string sender =  m.From.Address;
                    string subject = m.Subject;
                    string content = m.Body;

                    Assert.IsTrue(m.Subject.Equals("Demonstration Account - Purchase Order #590-22")
                        , "Order email was not found");

                    //Console.WriteLine("Email with subject {0} was sent by sender {1}, at {2},", m.Subject, sender, m.Date);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this mail or add another message(you doing assert's in loop, so it will fail on any iteration where subject not equals to "Demonstration Account - Purchase Order #590-22".

Or you can check if message is seen or not, and skip that already seen(and set message as seen in code if needed). This library don't set this flag automatically.

Also you are not doing unit testing here. It's integration testing. And this integration testing not for ImapClient, but mostly for standard .NET Framework "Lazy<T>" Collection. Which is nonsense - standard .Net Framework classes can be considered as tested by default.

For doing real unit testing first decide **what feature you wand to test**. And why you want to test it. Or else unit testing will be just huge useless waste of time.

Comment: Hi rufanov, 
It's obviously not a unit test. I wanted to use VSE Unit Test project as it is more convenient to run a bunch of tests regardless of them being proper unit tests or integration tests as this one is. The only thing I'm trying to achieve here is for the test to fail if the specific email is not found and pass if it does. Suggestions (In code) would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have changed the code as follows and its working as expected:

```
    using (ImapClient ic = new ImapClient(imapAddr, myEmailID, myPasswd, ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, portNo, secureConn))
        {
            ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
            bool headersOnly = false;
            Lazy<MailMessage>[] messages = ic.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen(), headersOnly);

            foreach (Lazy<MailMessage> message in messages)
            {
                MailMessage m = message.Value;

                string sender = m.From.Address;
                string subject = m.Subject;
                string content = m.Body;

                if (subject.Equals("QA3 - Purchase Order #3503-197"))//Change string accordingly. 
                    isEmailFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(isEmailFound, "Order email was not generated");
    }
```